# Trying to format a date for various systems

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite

At the moment I'm trying to work at a historical table for a project. I have an event date for this. This event date can be 2007-01-14 or 1977-01-09 but I also want these events to be displayed on 2020-01-14 or 2020-01-09, that I know something happened on those days.

At the moment I have this format in the query to see if anything happened on the current day.
`DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(date),'-',DAYOFMONTH(date)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as date`

In my development environment I work with MySQL, check the project with Sqlite in phpunit and test the project for production on Heroku with PostgreSQL.

Things like Sqlite and PostgreSQL don't have functions like CURDATE and so on.

How can I create my query with the requirement that the event be re-displayed each year so that it works in different systems?

Comment: Pick one database and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use database native data type to store data and use the format you want during display.
Storing data with proper data types may help in the future. You can use many system-defined date functions easily if you have stored data in the appropriate formate.